# Protected and private methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visibility, private, protected

Method visibility in Ruby (public, protected, and private methods) has been well explained in places like [this blog post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/23/method-visibility-in-ruby). But in Ruby on Rails it seems slightly different than it would be in a regular Ruby application because of the way the framework is set up. So, in Rails models, controllers, helpers, tests, etc., when is/isn't it appropriate to use protected or private methods?

**Edit**: Thanks for the answers so far. I understand the concept of protected and private in Ruby, but I'm looking more for an explanation of the typical way those types of visibility are used within the context of the various pieces of a Rails app (models, controllers, helpers, tests). For example, public controller methods are action methods, protected methods in the application controller are used for "helper methods" that need to be accessed by multiple controllers, etc.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For models, the idea is that the public methods are the public interface of the class. Public methods are intended to be used by other objects, while protected/private methods are to be hidden from the outside.

This is the same practice as in other object-oriented languages.

For <strike>controllers and</strike> tests, just do as you please. <strike>Both controller and</strike> test classes are only instantiated and called by the framework (<strike>yes, I know you can theoretically get the controller from the view, but if you do that, something is strange anyway</strike>). Since no one will ever create those things directly, there's nothing to "protect" against.

**Addendum/Correction:** For controllers, you should mark the "helper" methods as <strike>protected</strike> private, and only the actions themselves should be public. The framework will never route any incoming HTTP calls to actions/methods that are not public, so your helper methods should be protected in that way.

For helpers it will make no difference if a method is protected or private, since they are always called "directly".

You can mark stuff protected in all those cases if it makes things easier for you to understand, of course.

Comment: "*For controllers, you should mark the "helper" methods as protected, and only the actions themselves should be public.*" Are you advising not to have any private methods in controllers? Or should I not be reading that literally?

Comment: Nowadays I only use private. protected and private are used interchangeably in most places; but protected brings a strange behaviour that I never needed in the real world.

Comment: I tend to only use private as well. This also follows certain guidelines, such as [Thoughtbot's "Use private instead of protected when defining controller methods."](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/blob/98eede4e2d93d76b0e9e5bdedb6899985de6d574/style/README.md#L196)

Answer (score 69):

You use a private method if you want *no one else but `self`* to use a method. You use a protected method if you want something only `self and is_a?(self)` s can call.

A good use of protected might be if you had a "virtual" initialization method.

```
class Base
    def initialize()
        set_defaults()
        #other stuff
    end

    protected
    def set_defaults()
        # defaults for this type
        @foo = 7
        calculate_and_set_baz()
    end

    private
    def calculate_and_set_baz()
        @baz = "Something that only base classes have like a file handle or resource"
    end
end

class Derived < Base
    protected
    def set_defaults()
        @foo = 13
    end
end
```

@foo will have different values. and the Derived instances will not have @baz

Update:
Since I wrote this, some things have changed in Ruby 2.0+ Aaron Patterson has an excellent write up http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/09/07/protected-methods-and-ruby-2-0.html

Comment: Love how you said `self and is_a?(self)`. I've always explained protected methods as being available in children classes.

Comment: Attention here! This is an important difference to other languages: Private methods are *also* available in child classes. The only difference in private and protected is that you can call protected methods with "self.set_defaults", while private methods can only be called as "set_defaults".

Comment: A fine answer, but doesn't even contain the word Rails which is THE point of the question

Comment: Notice the Edit time stamp of his question. In the future I will define a private method to update my answers as they change their questions :)

Comment: As averell said, this explanation does not apply to ruby. Where private methods are also visible in child classes.

Comment: There have been some changes here in Ruby 2.0+. Aaron Patterson A.K.A. TenderLove has an excellent write up here. http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/09/07/protected-methods-and-ruby-2-0.html

Answer (score 11):

> The difference between protected and
>   private is subtle. If a method is
>   protected, it may be called by any
>   instance of the defining class or its
>   subclasses. If a method is private, it
>   may be called only within the context
>   of the calling object---it is never
>   possible to access another object
>   instance's private methods directly,
>   even if the object is of the same
>   class as the caller. For protected
>   methods, they are accessible from
>   objects of the same class (or
>   children).

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Declaring_Visibility

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I'm wondering more about how these work specifically in Ruby on Rails (public controller methods are treated as action methods, protected methods in the application controller can be used by other controllers, etc.)

Comment: In the last case "protected methods in the application controller can be used by other controllers" this is because the other controllers (generally) *inherit from* ApplicationController so they actually own all of those methods themselves.  They're not accessing them from application_controller: this doesn't ever get instantiated.  It's purely used as a parent to inherit from.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a good idea of the semantics of class visibility (public/protected/private) as applied to methods. All I can offer is a quick outline of the way I implement it in my Rails apps.

I implement protected methods in the base application controller so they can get called by any controller via filters (e.g. before_filter :method_foo). In a similar way, I define protected methods for models that I want to use in all of them in a base model that they all inherit from.

Answer (score 2):

Although actions need to be public methods of a controller, not all public methods are necessarily actions. You can use [`hide_action`](https://github.com/rails/hide_action) if you're using a catch-all route like `/:controller/:action/:id` or if it's disabled (the default in Rails 3) then only methods with explicit routes will be called.

This can be useful if you're passing the controller instance to some other library like the Liquid template engine as you can provide a public interface rather than having to use send in your Liquid filters and tags.