# how iterate from another model into the layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i'm looking to fetch the collection from one model to display over the all pages.

**Application.html.erb**

```
 <ul>
    <% @category.each do |c| %>
   <li><%= c.name %></li></ul>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
```

**Controller**

```
 @categories = Category.all
```

how I fit it in the Application controller  without having to copy and paste on all controllers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `ApplicationController.rb` create an `before_filter` and define it to call a specific method.

For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :load_categories

  protected
  def load_categories
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

Now, you should be able to access the `@categories` from all your views.

In your view:

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= c.name %></li></ul>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't believe you can set up instance variables in before filters. I've tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: yeah i tested the both methods and this did not worked for me as well

Comment: When I tried this, the variable was nil when used in the view. I remember reading an explanation as to why this is, but can't seem to find the article...

Comment: this is actually the best way to do it. Imagine in some controller action you want to only display a range of categories, you can just override the instance method in that action and it's done. Using the Model at the view there is no way to do this, only creating a new layout...

Comment: I have a question, why a protected method and not private one?

Comment: take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495078/protected-and-private-methods-in-rails). It should answer that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
<ul>
<% Category.all.each do |c| %>
 <li><%= c.name %></li></ul>
<% end %>
 </ul>
```

You don't have to set up an instance variable in the controller.