# What is the proper way to validate that a User's admin attribute is set to true in your controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Devise User model with the attribute admin of type boolean.  How can I specify in my controllers that only want certain actions to be available if admin = true?  Would the following authorize method work?

```
def authorize
redirect_to login_url, alert:"Not authorized" if current_user.admin == false
end
```

Here is my Users table, admin is a boolean.

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.string   "name"
end
```

Output of current_user inside the authorize_admin method using Pry:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for :authorize_admin:Symbol
```

I am using devise so shouldn't current_user work?

Here is the output of User.first in the console:

```
#<User id: 1, email: "email@gmail.com", encrypted_password:    

"$2a$10$RCgzx7PJho4vegbf8Z04eumTGB1RyDl5YvDeCAMz7g3...", reset_password_token: nil,   
 reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 5,   
 current_sign_in_at: "2014-10-25 23:42:17", last_sign_in_at: "2014-10-23 00:57:07", 
 current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at:   
 "2014-10-10   
19:24:39", updated_at: "2014-10-25 23:42:17", admin: false, image_file_name: nil,   
image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, name: nil>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I specify in my controllers that only want certain actions to be available if admin = true?

You can use [`rails before filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to achieve it. *You can define your authorize method in application controller, which will make this method available in all of your controllers.*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert:"Not authorized" if current_user.try(:admin) == false
  end
end
```

Now inside controller you can set before filter for methods you want to authorize.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize, only: [:your_action_name]
  def your_action_name
    #some action
  end
end
```

***If your code has a lot of customisation depending on admin and normal users then you can also use [`cancancan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)***

Comment: Thanks. Why should it be private?

Comment: I'm just getting thrown an "undefined method admin" error.  I just double checked my schema, admin is indeed a boolean property of the Users table with its default set to false.  I generated my User model with Devise if that effects anything?

Comment: @JoeSmith checkout [`this thread`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495078/protected-and-private-methods-in-rails) for using private methods. `undefined method admin` error suggests you don't have a admin field for current_user or basically users table. Can you post output of current_user from rails console or your schema?

Comment: I just edited my Users table into the question.  And I know what that usually means but admin is there so I am confused.

Comment: @JoeSmith Ah! That's strange. Can you post the output of current_user after using a debugger or pry

Comment: Sorry here it is: NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for :authorize_admin:Symbol

Comment: @JoeSmith ah okay i think i got it. When you are not logged in current_user is nil and so we are calling admin method on nil. Try updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Declarative Authorization gem](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) to control user access to controller actions and highly recommend it. It allows you to set up categories of users and then control which group has access to which controller actions. It's powerful, flexible and pretty easy to set up.