# Private methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

An example of Rails controller which defines a private method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def authorization_method
    # do something
  end
end
```

Then, it's being used in a subclass of `ApplicationController`:

```
class CustomerController < ApplicatioController
  before_action :authorization_method

  # controller actions
end
```

How is it possible that a private method is called from its subclass? What is the meaning of `private` in Ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protected and private methods in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495078/protected-and-private-methods-in-rails)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Ruby have both private and protected methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534449/why-does-ruby-have-both-private-and-protected-methods)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver. But they can be called by any subclasses and instances of the class.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3534581/5325238)'s a nice explanation of `public`, `protected` and `private` methods in Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

What `private` does in Ruby, unlike in other languages, is make so that methods can **not** be called with *explicit receiver*.

Aka, you can't call `some_variable.some_private_method` or even `self.some_private_method`.

That is all. They are still inherited. You can read more [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_access_control.html).

Answer (score 3):

The subclass inherits all of the methods and attributes from the superclass, including it's private methods. You are, in fact, calling the private method belonging to the subclass.

What you couldn't do is call authorization_method from outside ApplicationController (or subclasses of Authorization controller. Try this in the console:

```
 > ApplicationController.new.authorization_method
 # NoMethodError: protected method `authorization_method' called for #<ApplicationController:0x0000000bb65778>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel noted in [his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32524559/1426097) private method "cannot be called with an explicit receiver". In another words, you cannot call private method using "dot" notation. This is different from Java where you can call `this.privateMethod()`. In Ruby `self.private_method` fails, but you can call it as `private_method` instead.

But there is one more way to call private methods of *any* object, which Rails internally uses to call before/after actions.

If you have an instance `obj` with private `private_method`, you can invoke the method by:

```
obj.send :private_method
```

Reality is, there are no private methods in Ruby in a strict sense. Privacy is "just recommendation, not the rule".